# Override Function in javascript when Iframes are used

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

I have iFrame in my main html file and I'm loading a sub html in that iFrame.
Sub HTML has some functions like on click of anchor tag I'm calling a function and that function is  loading some page.
Now in my main iFrame when I click that anchor tag of sub HTML, I want to override that function, instead of loading I want to embed some file.
Right now both main html and sub html on click both are working. 
When I checked the event listener I saw main html click is first and then sub HTML click function. In that case how can I override it?
I have tried e.preventDefault() ,  e.stopImmediatePropagation();

Comment: Can you provide some code?

Comment: Your problem is ALMOST clear... Yet according to [this site standards](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) we need to be able to `reproduce` your problem. As I can see you are new here... Then provide a little code and let us see how many minutes it will take to propose one OR more solutons

Comment: Sub HTML has script.js where my below code is there
 var $pdf = { 
                        click: function () { window.onload('test.pdf') } 
 };
$pdf will load after the pop up

Main html overriding function is below
$('a').on('click', function(e) {
    if (url.split('.').pop() === 'pdf') {
          e.stopImmediatePropagation();
    }
     else if ($(this).parent().hasClass('pdf') || $(this).hasClass('pdf') || $(this).hasClass('pdf-button-isi')){
      e.stopImmediatePropagation();
      /* EMBED CODE */
   }
}